# HTC Amaze 4G (Videotron) - Is there a way to install Android 4.0?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc, 4g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I just got my new HTC Amaze 4G with Videotron and I only have Android 2.3 on it. Videotron says that they will release Android 4.0 soon.

Is there a way to install it before this? Like a Beta or something like that?

Comment: Do you find the way to upgrade your andriod to new version. I have the same issue.

Comment: Well, I got the update finally, but not the 4.1 so I sold the device and bought a Galaxy Nexus. Much better phone, and updates directly from Google. Currently on 4.2.2 Jelly Bean.

Comment: to which version you are able to upgrade the HTC amaze? and how?

Comment: I got the 4.0.1 update, by Videotron. I received a notification and did it via the built-in updater. Worked perfectly!